# How to display vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to display all the vocabulary that i've created in the /fr/admin/structure/taxonomy page and each vocabulary linked to the list of terms it containes.

How can display them in a page ?

Comment: where you want to display?

Comment: @vgoradiya In a page for example.

Comment: Use views for it.

Comment: @vgoradiya I've tried views, views only can help to display Taxonomy terms not the vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by creating a view only. Please find the attached screenshots.[image][image]

Comment: This isn't exactly what was asked - OP sounds like they want to list the _names_ of the vocabulary, which link to a page with terms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but what @Kevin is saying is right, i want a page that lists the Vocabulary and each vocabulary is linked to display it's terms of taxonomy